# iPad HTML5 canvas not refreshing

Tags: javascript, ipad, html, canvas, touch

**Edit: Demo Code is found in the "parallelogram explorer" tab here: http://atmdev01.procloud.net/geometry_tools9/**

So I'm calling the following javascript function at document load to draw the perimeter of a parallelogram, and it is working just fine to do that.  The issue is when I call the function from the touchmove handler to allow an iPad user to adjust the size of the parallelogram, the canvas is not properly redrawing the shape.  In fact it is not responding at all.  I've run some alerts to verify that this function is actually being run and it is.

Could it be an issue with the way I'm clearing the canvas (the "canvas.width = canvas.width + 0" method) or simply with refresh rates on the iPad?

The interesting part is that it's working perfectly in a desktop browser using mousemove, but not on an iPad using touchmove.  Please advise...

(the "corners" in the code are the areas where the user can touch and drag to resize the parallelogram)

```
this.drawSides = function() {
    var order = [1, 2, 4, 3];
    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var firstCorner = this.getCornerObj(1);
    var secondCorner = this.getCornerObj(2);    
    var firstCornerOpp = this.getCornerObj(firstCorner.opp);
    var secondCornerOpp = this.getCornerObj(secondCorner.opp);      

    /* Clear the canvas and draw a parallelogram with the provided corners */
    canvas.width = canvas.width + 0; //clears the canvas faster than clearRect
    ctx.beginPath();
    for (i in order) {
        if (i < order.length) {
            var cornerObj = this.getCornerObj(order[i]);
            if (order[i] > 1) {
                var prevObj = this.getCornerObj(order[i-1]);
                ctx.moveTo(prevObj.x  + (prevObj.width)/2, prevObj.y + (prevObj.height)/2);
                ctx.lineTo(cornerObj.x + (cornerObj.width)/2, cornerObj.y + (cornerObj.height)/2);                  
            }
        }
    }

    ctx.lineTo(firstCorner.x + (firstCorner.width)/2, firstCorner.y + (firstCorner.height)/2);
    ctx.strokeStyle = "#300";
    ctx.stroke();
}
```

Comment: Providing a portion of your code is nice. Much better, though, would be to host a reproducible pared-down test case online showing the interaction of all your pieces.

Comment: @Phrogs Here is a demo: http://atmdev01.procloud.net/geometry_tools9/

Comment: Thanks; when I get home to my iPad I'll take a look. (If you had spelled my name correctly, I would have seen this last night. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've resolved this issue. Turns out the issue was that I wasn't properly updating my cornerObjects' x and y coordinates on touchmove. (the code excerpt above has no issue)

Also, for future reference, canvas.width = canvas.width + 0; works just fine on Safari and the iPad.

Answer (score 4):

The canvas isn't cleared properly with `canvas.width = canvas.width;` in safari.

Comment: I previously had ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height); in there for that line, but that didn't seem to work either - and is more costly in terms of efficiency.  Any other suggestions?

Comment: Either method of clearing seems to yield a successful result on my Macbook's Safari, although it is leaving some "streaks" behind.  This leads me to believe that it's an issue of the iPad not being able to handle the redraw rate.  In my research over the past few days, I've only come across those two methods of clearing the canvas, is there another way to do it?

Comment: Low end machines do struggle with redrawing the canvas a lot, you could try running your method on low end computer, to see if its either an issue with too outdated hardware or if it's exclusively an iPad problem.

Comment: @Matt Clearing less of the rect if possible is one way to do it. Still, you should see some result of your redraw. Try out some of these demos on your iPad to see that it can keep up at least somewhat: [beachball](http://phrogz.net/tmp/canvas_beachball.html); [flag wave](http://phrogz.net/tmp/canvas_flag_wave2.html); [gauge](http://phrogz.net/tmp/canvas_gauge.html); [spiral](http://phrogz.net/tmp/canvas_spiral_4.html); [zoom](http://phrogz.net/tmp/canvas_spiral_7.html); [image move speed test](http://phrogz.net/tmp/image_move_speed.html) (click the table headers for tests)

Comment: @abloodywar @Phrogs Thanks guys for the suggestions, it looks like I can rule out the idea of this being a memory issue on the particular iPad, as all of the links above run just fine on the iPad.  I also ran it in a low-end browser and it appears to work just fine.  May be an issue of calling the function on every touchmove event?  I'm starting to run out of ideas...

Comment: @abloodywar @Phrogz I've resolved this issue.  Turns out the issue was that I wasn't properly updating my cornerObjects' x and y coordinates on touchmove.  (the code excerpt above has no issue)  Also, for future reference, canvas.width = canvas.width + 0; works just fine on the iPad.

Answer (score 3):

Keep in mind that it's less computationally expensive to clear the canvas using context.clearRect() than it is to reset the canvas size.  This is really important for mobile devices and tablets.

Reference: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/canvas/performance/#toc-clear-canvas